# Trying to convert WAV to HE-AACv2

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-conversion, aac, wav

so I've been trying to figure out how to convert WAVs into HE-AACv2, and nothing seems to be working at all. When I get an output file, it's corrupted. When I don't, it's always some vague error that no one knows about on the Discord server. I've read the wiki pages on this, I've read other documentation, and I've tried every option it says on any of them, and nothing works, I haven't gotten a single file to play from this process.

Here's one of my many commands (this is one of the ones that gives me a corrupted audio file for the output): ./ffmpeg -i "Cinnamon Road.wav" -b:a aac_at -profile:a aac_he_v2 -b:a 160k "Cinnamon Road_HE-AACv2_160k.m4a"
This command also doesn't generate any errors, the file is just corrupted.

Here's what the output in Terminal looks like:

```
MiniBlade:~ jaden$ ./ffmpeg -i "Cinnamon Road.wav" -b:a aac_at -profile:a aac_he_v2 -b:a 160k "Cinnamon Road_HE-AACv2_160k.m4a"
ffmpeg version 6.0-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'Cinnamon Road.wav':
  Duration: 00:03:58.93, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
File 'Cinnamon Road_HE-AACv2_160k.m4a' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, ipod, to 'Cinnamon Road_HE-AACv2_160k.m4a':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 aac
size=    4732kB time=00:03:58.91 bitrate= 162.2kbits/s speed=38.1x       
video:0kB audio:4691kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.874955%
[aac @ 0x7f854050ca80] Qavg: 1462.787
MiniBlade:~ jaden$
```

I read somewhere that I might have to build ffmpeg myself using code to "enable" the options I'm trying to use, but I'm not trying to do anything fancy, I'm simply trying to convert a WAV to HE-AACv2, and I really shouldn't have to do this, but in the case that I did, I tried to build it and my OS is too old, I'm on MacOS 10.14, and I will not be updating this machine.

Comment: What players claim that the output is corrupted?

Comment: Replace `-b:a aac_at` by `-c:a aac_at`